# Angular: Catching response error description in http.post request

Tags: c#, angular, error-handling

I have an Angular login method that receives a token from a Asp.Net Web Api from a post request and in case credentials are not correct I throw an "invalid_grant" error like it can be seen in the next piece of C# code:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            SetContextHeaders(context);
            string strDomain = Settings.Default.ADDomain;

            try
            {
                using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, strDomain))
                {
                    // validate the credentials
                    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(context.UserName, context.Password);

                    if (!isValid)
                    {
                        context.SetError("invalid_grant", Culture.GetResxNameByValue("wfrh_auth_incorrectusernamepassword"));
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (PrincipalServerDownException ex) {
                context.SetError("adserver_not_reachable", Culture.GetResxNameByValue("wfrh_auth_serverunreachable"));
                LogUtils.logText(Utils.getRunningAssembly(), Utils.getRunningMethod(), ex.InnerException.Message);
                return;
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);
        }
```

And browser receives the error as 400 "Bad Request" but in the details of the error in network tab you can see:

```
{error: "invalid_grant", error_description: "Incorrect username or password."}
error
:
"invalid_grant"
error_description
:
"Incorrect username or password."
```

Which is correct, but I'm not being able to catch that error description in my Angular method. All I receive is a string with "Bad Request" literal.

This is my login method:

```
let headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    })
}

let tokenParams = "grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:9810/token', tokenParams, headers)
    .pipe(
        map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user && user.access_token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ user }));
                return user;
            }
            return user;
        }) , catchError((err:JSON) => {
            console.log("" + err);
            return Observable.throw(err);
        }),
    );
```

The fact is I'm new to Angular and I don't have much experience in error handling.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Update 1:

The most weird thing is that executing http.post from AngularJS as seen below works great.

```
$http({
    url: baseUrl + '/token',
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    data: 'grant_type=password' + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password
}).then(function (response) {
    alert(response.data.access_token);
}, function (response) {
    alert(response.data.error_description);
});
```

Comment: Try using pipe(....).catch((error)=>{})

Comment: Thanks for replying @Ranjeet Avghad. If I try to use catch lint complains with error "[ts] Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'". BTW, I'm using Angular 6.

Comment: definition might be wrong try using different definitions   i am using this 
 - pipe(....).catch((error:any, cought:Observable<T>)=>{})

Comment: I've been reading a lot but still no luck. The only thing I have clear is that in Angular 6 catch was replaces by catchError but I write it correctly and still get only "Bad Request" with no error_description property :(